# Multiple exclusive OR filter in a bool Query

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

In the Previous version of the Nest ie in 1.x multiple exclusive or filters were allowed like the below raw query

AS orFilters are no more recommended in 2.x what could be the replacement for this. How to have multiple exclusive should(s) (orfilters) along with a Must in a Bool Query?

Raw query from 1.x

```
  {
       "bool": {
         "must": [
           {
             "bool": {
               "must": [
                 {
                   "term": {
                     "EntityType": "ITSTrucks"
                   }
                 },
                 {
                   "or": {
                     "filters": [
                       {
                         "term": {
                           "AvailableDate": 36523
                         }
                       },
                       {
                         "range": {
                           "AvailableDate": {
                             "gte": "42036"
                           }
                         }
                       }
                     ],
                     "_name": "date"
                   }
                 },
                 {
                   "or": {
                     "filters": [
                       {
                         "geo_distance": {
                           "OriginCoordinate": "42.815656,-73.942324",
                           "distance": "100miles",
                           "distance_type": "plane"
                         }
                       }
                     ],
                     "_name": "OriginOrFilter"
                   }
                 },
                 {
                   "or": {
                     "filters": [
                       {
                         "term": {
                           "IsOpen": true
                         }
                       },
                       {
                         "term": {
                           "IsDestinationBoundaryNull": true
                         }
                       }
                     ],
                     "_name": "DestinationOrFilter"
                   }
                 }
               ]
             }
           }
         ]
       }
     }
```

Will something like this ?

```
    BoolQueryDescriptor<AvailableTrucks>  queryParameterMust= new BoolQueryDescriptor<AvailableTrucks>();
    BoolQueryDescriptor<AvailableTrucks> queryParameterShouldFirst= new BoolQueryDescriptor<AvailableTrucks>();
    BoolQueryDescriptor<AvailableTrucks> queryParameterShouldSecond= new BoolQueryDescriptor<AvailableTrucks>();
    BoolQueryDescriptor<AvailableTrucks> queryParameterShouldThird= new BoolQueryDescriptor<AvailableTrucks>();
    if (mustfc.Count > 0)
    {
        queryParameterMust.Must(mustfc.ToArray());
    }
    if (shouldQueryListFirst.Count > 0)
    {
        queryParameterShouldFirst.Should(shouldQueryListFirst.ToArray());
    }
    if (ShouldQueryListSecond.Count > 0)
    {
        queryParameterShouldSecond.Should(ShouldQueryListSecond.ToArray());
    }
    if (ShouldQueryListThird.Count > 0)
    {
        queryParameterShouldThird.Should(ShouldQueryListThird.ToArray());
    }
elasticClient.Search<Truck>(s => s.Query(f => f.Bool(c => c.Must(u => u.MatchAll()).Filter(q => q.Bool(b => queryParameterMust && queryParameterShouldFirst && queryParameterShouldSecond && queryParameterShouldThird)))))>Index("Trucks")
```

Comment: I don't know of an EXOR ability in elasticsearch, but you have AND (must), OR (should) and NOT (must_not), so you could make your own EXOR. a EXOR b == (a AND NOT b) OR (b AND NOT a)

Answer (score 0):

In 2.x.x version you can use `Should` term for logic OR queries.

Some example:

```
{
    "bool" : {
        "must" : {
            "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
        }
        "should" : [
            {
                "term" : { "tag" : "wow" }
            },
            {
                "term" : { "tag" : "elasticsearch" }
            }
        ],
        "minimum_should_match" : 1
    }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Please note you can also nest those terms.

To build query using NEST you could try:

```
var mustMatchQueries = new List<QueryContainer>()
var shouldMatchQueries = new List<QueryContainer>();

// ... add queries to both lists

// aggregate queries
var mustMatchAggregatedTerms = mustMatchQueries.Aggregate(new QueryContainer(), (s, ff) => s &= ff);
var shouldMatchAggregatedTerms = shouldMatchQueries.Aggregate(new QueryContainer(), (s, ff) => s |= ff);

// build descriptor
var descriptor = new SearchDescriptor<DocumentClassName>()
descriptor.Query(q => q.Bool(b => b.Must(m => mustMatchAggregatedTerms && m.Bool(c => c.Should(shouldMatchAggregatedTerms)))));
```

Comment: The `should` behaves differently in a query context to a filter context. I think the OP wants it inside a filter context.